# sum, average, min, max, and total number of negative values

Tags: c++

I'm supposed to output the total number of values SUM, AVERAGE, MIN, MAX and total numbers of negative values. i was got the SUM, I  been unable to get the average in decimals; As for the MAX, MIN, and total number of negative numbers, my code is not working. can you point me into the right direction of how to fix my code to count the number of negative values, and  MIN/MAX using these given values: 14.7, -2.8, 105.2, -56.8, 0, 8.4, -20.4

```
int sum = 0;
double number;
double values;`enter code here`
int averagevalues;
int negativevalues;
float min=500, max=0;

cout << "Hello everybody!! \n";
cout << "How many values would you like to enter? XD \n";
cin >> values;

for(int i=0;i<values;i++)
{
    cout << "Enter number: \n";
    cin >> number;

    sum=sum+number;

}
cout<<"The sum of all values is: "<< sum<<endl;

averagevalues = static_cast<double>(sum)/values;
cout<<"The average value is: "<< averagevalues<<endl;

for (int i = 0; i<values;i++)
{
    if (values < min)
    {
        min = values;
    }

    if (values > max)
    {
        max = values;
    }
}


for (int i = 0;i<values;i++)
{
    if (values < 0)
    {
        negativevalues = values++;
    }
}

cout << "The MIN of the numbers you gave me is: " << min <<endl;
cout << "The MAX of the given numbers is: " << max <<endl;
cout << " Total number of negative values is: " << negativevalues <<endl;
```

Comment: The code is good, but do you have any question?

Comment: I don't recall ``enter code here`` being a valid C or C++ statement

Comment: Try #define MAX(a,b) (a > b) ? a : b

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: @ScY Bad idea, you will have problems calculating `MAX(++a, b)`

Comment: @ScY `std::max` should be preferred over that macro.  Macros still have a place in C++ but `max` is not one of them.

Comment: `sum` and `averagevalue` are integers, that might be your problem. `negativevalues` is not initialized, that is another problem. `

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 True, that would be quite bad, but for comparisons with no side-effects that should be good enough.

Comment: @ScY No, you will also have problems calculating `MAX(a & b, c)`, due to operator precedence. Actually, given that one should be EXTREMELY careful when both writing and using macros, much simpler solution would be to just avoid them, except for some very special cases.

Comment: @ScY And also, code like `MAX(a, b)cde` will be expanded into `(a > b) ? a : bcde` - an interesting side-effect if you have a variable named `bcde`.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 You can always write something like #define MAX(a, b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b)) to avoid operator precedence problems. Btw, I don't advocate the use of macros over well-defined functions, but a macro was the first thing that came to my mind when I saw OPs question...

Comment: Also, `values` just contains *the number of* values, not the `number`s themselves. You would have to do most of the comparisons inside the loop that reads `number`.

Comment: @ScY: No matter the circumstance, a macro should never be the _first_ thing on your mind. The right time for macro's is "It's time either to use a macro, or sacrifice a goat to the C++ gods, and I'm all out of goats".

Answer (score 0):

In the loop at the end of your code, variable `values` is just the number of values that user enters. So you are not comparing the numbers that user enters.

Try allocating an array of doubles (or whatever type you want) to store the numbers, then compare them with min and max values.